# Django Rest Framework use DjangoModelPermissions on ListAPIView

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am playing around with the `djangorestframework` and my goal is to use `DjangoModelPermissions` on my view which reacts to a `GET` request. The official documentation says:

> The default behavior can also be overridden to support custom model
>   permissions. For example, you might want to include a `view` model
>   permission for `GET` requests.

[Source](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions/#djangomodelpermissions)

So I modified my model like the following:

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    display_name = models.CharField(_('Display Name'), blank=True, max_length=255)

    class Meta:
        permissions = (
            ("view_user", "Can view users"),
        )

    def __str__(self):
        return self.username
```

And the view:

```
class UserListAPIView(ListAPIView):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
    permission_classes = (permissions.DjangoModelPermissions,)
```

Settings:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',
    ),
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.permissions.DjangoModelPermissions'
    ]
}
```

The problem is that my implemented `UserListAPIView` successfully returns a list of all objects to a user who doesn't belong to a `Group` neither has any custom `User Permission`. It seems to me that the `DjangoModelPermissions` takes no effect.

Comment: Oh, I think I have to implement it by myself: https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/permissions.py#L91 Any help here would be appreciated though.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Ouch, that was easier than I thought:

```
class CustomDjangoModelPermission(permissions.DjangoModelPermissions):

    def __init__(self):
        self.perms_map = copy.deepcopy(self.perms_map)  # from EunChong's answer
        self.perms_map['GET'] = ['%(app_label)s.view_%(model_name)s']
```

Comment: After a couple of hours searching it saved me!

Comment: After a couple of days, I found out that perms_map is a class variable, and after  that I've read EunChong answer.

Answer (score 10):

@Yannic Hamann's solution has a small bug. It overwrites parent's perms_map['GET'].

As follows, A dictionary overring need deepcopy.

```
class CustomDjangoModelPermission(permissions.DjangoModelPermissions):

    def __init__(self):
        self.perms_map = copy.deepcopy(self.perms_map) # you need deepcopy when you inherit a dictionary type 
        self.perms_map['GET'] = ['%(app_label)s.view_%(model_name)s']
```

---

> **dictionary overring test**

```
class Parent:
    perms = {'GET':'I am a Parent !'}

class Child(Parent):
    def __init__(self):
        self.perms['GET'] = 'I am a Child !'
```

> **dictionary overring result**

```
>>> print(Parent().perms['GET'])
I am a Parent !

>>> print(Child().perms['GET'])
I am a Child !

>>> print(Parent().perms['GET'])
I am a Child ! # Parent's perms is overwritten by Child.
       ^^^^^
```

Comment: can you inline code/output rather than screen shot it. It's easier to read and better for usability

Comment: @Lex thanks, I fixed. inline code/output is better :D

Answer (score 2):

You have to override the custome DjangoModelPermissions.

```
class BaseModelPerm(permissions.DjangoModelPermissions):

     def get_custom_perms(self, method, view):
          app_name = view.model._meta.app_label
          return [app_name+"."+perms for perms in view.extra_perms_map.get(method, [])]

    def has_permission(self, request, view):
       perms = self.get_required_permissions(request.method, view.model)
       perms.extend(self.get_custom_perms(request.method, view))
       return (
          request.user and
          (request.user.is_authenticated() or not self.authenticated_users_only) and
        request.user.has_perms(perms)
    )
```

in the view you can use like below

```
class ViewName(generic.ListApiView):

      """ Trip listing view """

     model = model_name
     serializer_class = serializer_class
     permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated,BaseModelPerm)
     queryset = model.objects.all()
     extra_perms_map = {
      'GET': ["can_view_trip"],
     }
```

add the whatever extra permissions you want to add.

Answer (score 0):

Following @Yannic Hamann's solution by design the developer should not call the init method instead it is called by Python when an instance of the class is created,
for scalability, you can add new permission to the dictionary in your custom model permission

```
class CustomModelPermissions(permissions.DjangoModelPermissions):
    """
    Custom ModelPermissions:
        -This permission must only be applied to views that have a .queryset property or get_queryset() method
        -Authorization will only be granted if the user is authenticated and has the relevant model permissions assigned
    """

    def get_required_permissions(self, method, model_cls):
        "Use append to add more action to GET,POST,PUT,PATCH As in"

        """
        self.perms_map['GET'].append('%(app_label)s.view_%(model_name)s'), THIS IS TO ENSURE YOU DO NOT OVERIDE THE EXISING METHOD permmsions
        """
        self.perms_map["GET"].append("%(app_label)s.view_%(model_name)s")
        return super().get_required_permissions(method, model_cls)
```