Django Model Permissions. Why is this hard?
Django creates permissions for every model you make, such as:
can_view_{model_name}
can_add_{model_name}
can_edit_{model_name}
Out of the box, these are only applicable to Django Admin. Ok well if I want to apply them at the model level, why can't I do:
class MyModel(models.Model)
    def can_view(self, user):
        if user.has_perm('my_app.can_view_my_model'):
            return True
        return False

And then any time the ORM tries to lookup that model, it has to check the permission first.
Instead, I have to go into each View and manually check:
class MyModelDetail(APIView):

    @transaction.atomic
    def get(self, request):
        try:
            if not request.user.has_perm("my_app.can_view_my_model"):
                raise APIException("You do not have permission to view this model")

And repeat that across all views that look up my model.
Is there an easier way?

Have you tried using a DjangoModelPermissions permission class? See https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions/#djangomodelpermissions and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46584653/django-rest-framework-use-djangomodelpermissions-on-listapiview

That's only applicable to a list view. "This permission must only be applied to views that have a .queryset property or get_queryset() method"

Any generic view, including detail views, also have this. You needn't only use list views.

I don't see APIView listed there. Are you suggesting I need to break out an APIView into its Generic Classes? I don't see how that's better..

Yes. Alternatively, instead of using a generic view, you could define queryset yourself.

"This permission must only be applied to views that have a .queryset property or get_queryset() method" is referring to >object< permissions.  The previous section explains how to deal with permission checks that can be done with standard permission classes.  And a later section explains how to create custom permission classes.  Your example doesn't look like an object permission.

And to answer your "why can't" question ... those permissions refer to specific functionality of the Admin pages.  Extending them to have more general semantics is ... not something that all Django devs would want. (In an ideal world, maybe Django could have a more uniform authorization / permission framework across web pages, rest pages, the admin interface, etc.  But you also need to take account of the entire history of Django when critiquing the design decisions.  Backwards compatibility is a major concern.)

You can do that, you will just have to implement that in the APIView, so mix it in.

@NickODell I don't understand what you're proposing. Define a queryset in an APIView?

@StephenC I don't see what it's illustrated how to implement at the APIView. Perhaps you can provide an answer. I'm not critiquing design decisions, but when a client is asking can we ensure that a user can't create an object at the model layer and I have to say ... no that's not supported by Django ... doesn't fare very well.

@willeM_VanOnsem You can't just add DjangoModelPermissions to an APIView as it will complain that "Cannot apply DjangoModelPermissions on a view that does not set .queryset or have a .get_queryset() method."

@AlxVallejo: I'm talking about has_object_permission: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions/#custom-permissions you could even use that as a "double OO dispatching mechanism" if you want.

Using a simple .get will of course not work, since then you essentially circumvent the permissions, but it works for a GenericAPIView, or ModelViewSet.

@StephenC Also, i don't see how you're correct in it applying to object permissions. It's clearly stated at DjangoModelPermissions, which is what the top comment is alluding to.

@willeM_VanOnsem I didn't think this was object permissions tho. If you have a solution, post it and i'll try it out.

@AlxVallejo: the base permission has two methods: has_permission to first check the request, without the object, and for object-oriented requests (like retrieving, updating, etc. a single object), it then uses .has_object_permission.

As for the can_add permission, that looks strange, since that is not object-related: you don't add on a model object, perhaps a model class itself.

@willeM_VanOnsem That's all great and stuff, but unless there's like a concrete solution proposed, i don't see how anything is going to beat just checking the permissions at each view method, sadly.

The Django REST framework has BasePermission classes [drf-doc] that can be used for this. Such permission could look like:
from rest_framework import permissions


class AdminModelPermission(permissions.BasePermission):
    METHOD_MAPPING = {
        'GET': 'view',
        'POST': 'add',
        'PUT': 'edit',
        'PATCH': 'edit',
        'DELETE': 'delete',
    }

    def has_permission(self, request, view):
        meta = view.get_queryset().model._meta
        action = self.METHOD_MAPPING.get(request.method)
        if action is not None:
            return request.user.has_perm(
                f'{meta.app_label}.{action}_{meta.model_name}'
            )
        return True

    def has_object_permission(self, request, view, obj):
        action = self.METHOD_MAPPING.get(request.method)
        if action is not None:
            method = getattr(obj, f'can_{action}', None)
            if method is not None:
                return method(request.user)
        return True
and then plug this in in a GenericAPIView or GenericViewSet or ModelViewSet, like:
from rest_framework import viewsets


class MyModelViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = MyModel.objects.all()
    permission_classes = (AdminModelPermission,)
If we now for example fire a DELETE request, it will first check if the user has a app_label.delete_mymodel permission. If so, it will fetch the object, and if the model itself has a .can_delete(…) method, it will call that with the logged in user to check if it can delete that specific object. If so, then finally it will proceed.
It is however important to at least fetch the object through the .get_object(…), since that is where the Django REST framework checks the .has_object_permission(…) of all installed permissions, and furthermore let it do the dispatching itself to invoke the .has_permission(…) method.

ok this seems like a great approach that i have not seen elsewhere. i'll report back on how this turns out.
